# Theano function analyse givens

Tags: theano

How can we monitor/analyse the `givens` of a theano function?

As an example consider the following function:

```
train_model = theano.function(
    inputs=[index],
    outputs=cost,
    updates=updates,
    givens={
        x: X_train[index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size],
        y: y_train[index * batch_size: (index + 1) * batch_size]
    }
)
```

What would be a way to monitor/analyse the shared variables x and y?

Comment: What are you trying achieve? Monitoring suggests looking at things that are changing but the givens in your example are, presumably, shared variables whose contents don't change over the course of a Theano function's execution.

Comment: @DanielRenshaw thank you for pointing out my conceptual mistake. I am trying to analyse contents of shared variables x and y. Pardon my novice question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're following/using the code from the Theano tutorials, as appears to be the case, then `x_train` and `y_train` are shared variables containing your training data (`x_train` is the input and `y_train` is the true/actual output that you want your model to predict when correct).

The contents of these shared variables never (or, at least, shouldn't) change because your training data is normally static while a model is training.

So, looking at the contents of shared variables `train_x` and `train_y` is just the same as looking at your training data. You can presumably just go look at the data wherever you load it from (e.g. maybe CSV data files, or numpy saved arrays, etc.)

If you really want to look at the contents of a shared variable then you can do this using the `get_value()` method which returns the underlying numpy array:

```
x_data = X_train.get_value()
print x_data.shape
# etc.
```

Theano is not involved at all here. Nothing is symbolic, it's just concrete numpy arrays.

Comment: Thanks for explaining clearly! Just one follow up question, as explained to get the value of the numpy array `X_train.get_value()` shouldn't the statement `X_train.eval()` work too?

Comment: Yes, it probably does work. But `eval()` is intended to be used sparingly as a debugging facility, is generally slow, and only really helps when dealing with symbolic expressions anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!